# LaTex failed to compile - R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have been trying to knit into a PDF file and I am always getting an error message at end:

```
Sorry, but C:\Users\mklin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
```

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

```
  C:\Users\mklin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Error: LaTeX failed to compile HW1_457.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
Execution halted
```

I have visited this website and installed packages with updating each as well. All of my files are in same folder. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try to change miktex to texlive at first.

Comment: Can you tell us what C:\Users\mklin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log says?

Comment: what about running `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`